# How can i know which element activated a click event in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a website and i want to execute the same action when two buttons are clicked. I tried  creating one single function that would be called by each button by using `.addEventListener ("click",function())`

But i wonder is there a way to know which button called it? for example if i wanted to add a condition inside the function that takes a decision depending on which element called it?

Comment: You can use the event argument of your event listener: `.addEventListener ("click",function(event))` and then use `event.target` inside your function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you pass the function, it receives an event. That event holds a [PointerEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PointerEvent), so that type is an object with many properties of the element, one of them is `target`, and the target can get the id of each element like so:

```
<body>
    <button id="b1">
        button1
    </button>
    <button id="b2">
        button2
    </button>
</body>
<script>
    const button1 = document.getElementById('b1')
    const button2 = document.getElementById('b2')

    const myCustomListener = function(e) {
        console.log(e.target.id) // b1 or b2
    }

    button1.addEventListener('click', myCustomListener )
    button2.addEventListener('click', myCustomListener )
</script>
```

You can also add event listeners dynamically to the buttons like so:

```
<body>
    <button id="b1" class="button">
        button1
    </button>
    <button id="b2" class="button">
        button2
    </button>
</body>
<script>
    const buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('button')

    const myCustomListener = function(e) {
        console.log(e.target.id) // b1 or b2
    }

    for (let button of buttons) {
        button.addEventListener('click', myCustomListener)
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

`id`s are useful for this (as Juliano points out). Alternatively you could add a descriptive [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) to each button to identify it (here I've used `type`). In the handler you can [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the `type` from the [button's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) dataset, and then do *x* depending on its value.

```js
// Get the buttons
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');

// Add listeners to them
buttons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
});

function handleClick(e) {

  // Destructure the type from the button dataset
  const { type } = e.target.dataset;
  if (type === 'fruit') console.log('Banana');
  if (type === 'vegetable') console.log('Potato');
}
```

```html
<section class="buttons">
  <button data-type="fruit">Surprise fruit!</button>
  <button data-type="vegetable">Surprise vegetable!</button>
</section>
```